# How to find in the body, if there are elements of this class

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing code in pure javascript, how can I find if there any class='active' on my `a` (`ul>li>a`).

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-0">Item0</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-1">Item1</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-2">Item2</a></li>
    <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-3">Item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**my js**

```
document.getElementsByClassName('active')
```

Comment: you question subject and content inside are not matching.

Comment: Also, if you want to find active a inside ul > li you could use a more complex selector "document.querySelectorAll('ul li a.active')"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs")[0].getElementsByClassName("active") // like this
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul li a.active') // or like this @Jhuliano Moreno 
for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  elements[i].classList.remove("active")
}

// Inefficiant on-liner:
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('ul li a.active'),0).forEach(function(el){el.classList.remove("active")})
```

```css
.active {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-0">Item0</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-1">Item1</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-2">Item2</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-3 active">Item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

**OLD:**

```js
if (document.getElementsByClassName('active').length > 0) {
    // Yes there are
  } else {
    // No there are not
  }
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-0">Item0</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-1">Item1</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-2">Item2</a></li>
  <li class="tabs-content"><a href="#" onclick="activatetb(this)" class="item-3 active">Item3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, whats the problem?

Comment: This doesn't answer.

Comment: Looks like @ Praveen Kumar is trolling me

Comment: Voted up, ha ha. LoL.

Comment: @PraveenKumar your answer doesn't answer the question, his answer does.

Comment: I understood @JhulianoMoreno That's why voted it up.

Comment: Now I just realised the missleading title "How to remove active class form a inside ul>li". Looks like there are two diffrent Questions :(

Comment: @CodeiSir:i need to remove the active class from the element if it has initially and on click i need to add the active class just like a TAB

Comment: @CodeiSir: earlier i tried using let in my code but it logs me an error,can you suggest me,why let throwing an error?

Comment: `let` throws error if you are not using it properly. use `var` if you don't know what it does

Comment: @Jhuliano Moreno I was about to credit your suggestions of (querySelectorAll) ... I just needed 5 seconds to copy your name

Comment: @CodeiSir that is fine, thanks for the credit ;)! Also, I had no idea that let was a valid keyword in JS.

Comment: @JhulianoMoreno @ak1111 `let` is more like a variable in most programming languages and can only be defined once and only be used in local scope: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: one more addition,how if i want to make 3rd li>a active (statically)

Comment: use another class-name `activeAlways`? or skip the element in the loop by `if(i == 2) continue;` before the remove

Comment: i am restricted i cannot add any extra class into it,can't we do by getting nth child concept?

Comment: if(i == ID_TO_SCIP) continue;